# Selenium How to get only Text between HTML tags

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Good afternoon people,

How do I capture only the text value between 2 HTML tags

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code that prints the entire contents of the element (only everything messed up):

```
//get data grid
WebElement scprap = driver0.findElement(By.className("list2_body"));                    
System.out.println(scprap.getText());
```

follows part of HTML with data:

```
<tbody class="list2_body">
    <tr id="row_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" class="list_row list_odd  list_row_compact" style="" sys_id="__ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" record_class="u_resultadochassi_case" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case">
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1">
            <span class="input-group-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista" id="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" name="check_u_resultadochassi_case" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" data-original-title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista">
                <label for="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" style="" class="checkbox-label">
                    <span class="sr-only">Selecione o registro para ação: __ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=</span>
                </label>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1">
            <a href="u_resultadochassi_case.do?sys_id=__ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" style="margin-left:0px" title="Visualização __ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" aria-label="Visualizar Registro: __ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" data-use-href="true" data-popover-title="__ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" data-popover-title-is-html="false" aria-haspop="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-original-title="Visualização __ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ="></a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" href="task.do?sys_id=b9a0fccfdb38e30472b47a30ba9619e6&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">CS0390798</a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__YjlhMGZjY2ZkYjM4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ZTY=-ODM5MDM4Y2ZkYjM0YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5YmQ=" href="sn_customerservice_resultado_chassis.do?sys_id=839038cfdb34afc0cd3d32ffaa9619bd&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=1&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">
                <div class="datex date-calendar" title="6 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 12:39:00" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10/2018 09:39:00</div>
                <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="6 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 12:39:00" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10 09:39</div>
                <div class="datex date-timeago" title="01/10/2018 09:39:00" timeago="2018-10-01 12:39:00" data-original-title="01/10/2018 09:39:00" null="cerca de um mês atrás">cerca de um mês atrás</div>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">3VWDJ2160CM142442</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">OLQ4101</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">oFICIO N° C 1201/2018</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">02/10/2018 09:39:54</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">MG</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Baixa Realizada</td>
        <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" class="list_row list_even  list_row_compact" style="" sys_id="__ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" record_class="u_resultadochassi_case" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case">
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1">
            <span class="input-group-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista" id="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" name="check_u_resultadochassi_case" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" data-original-title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista">
                <label for="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" style="" class="checkbox-label">
                    <span class="sr-only">Selecione o registro para ação: __ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=</span>
                </label>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1">
            <a href="u_resultadochassi_case.do?sys_id=__ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=2&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" style="margin-left:0px" title="" aria-label="Visualizar Registro: __ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" data-use-href="true" data-popover-title="__ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" data-popover-title-is-html="false" aria-haspop="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-original-title="Visualização __ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE="></a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" href="task.do?sys_id=3f523c47db78e30472b47a30ba961959&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=2&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">CS0390811</a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__M2Y1MjNjNDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NTk=-YTE1MmY0MDdkYjc4ZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NGE=" href="sn_customerservice_resultado_chassis.do?sys_id=a152f407db78e30472b47a30ba96194a&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=2&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">
                <div class="datex date-calendar" title="6 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 12:48:36" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10/2018 09:48:36</div>
                <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="6 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 12:48:36" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10 09:48</div>
                <div class="datex date-timeago" title="01/10/2018 09:48:36" timeago="2018-10-01 12:48:36" data-original-title="01/10/2018 09:48:36" null="cerca de um mês atrás">cerca de um mês atrás</div>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">9BGVP15ENMB102056</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">JKU8367</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Baixa Administrativa</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">02/10/2018 09:49:26</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">MG</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Baixa Realizada</td>
        <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" class="list_row list_odd  list_row_compact" style="" sys_id="__ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" record_class="u_resultadochassi_case" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case">
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1">
            <span class="input-group-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista" id="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" name="check_u_resultadochassi_case" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" data-original-title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista">
                <label for="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" style="" class="checkbox-label">
                    <span class="sr-only">Selecione o registro para ação: __ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=</span>
                </label>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1">
            <a href="u_resultadochassi_case.do?sys_id=__ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=3&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" style="margin-left:0px" title="Visualização __ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" aria-label="Visualizar Registro: __ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" data-use-href="true" data-popover-title="__ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" data-popover-title-is-html="false" aria-haspop="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-original-title="Visualização __ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk="></a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" href="task.do?sys_id=71a24d47db7ce30472b47a30ba961930&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=3&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">CS0390940</a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__NzFhMjRkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MzA=-YWI4MmNkNDdkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5Mjk=" href="sn_customerservice_resultado_chassis.do?sys_id=ab82cd47db7ce30472b47a30ba961929&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=3&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">
                <div class="datex date-calendar" title="" timeago="2018-10-01 13:59:32" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10/2018 10:59:32</div>
                <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="6 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 13:59:32" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10 10:59</div>
                <div class="datex date-timeago" title="01/10/2018 10:59:32" timeago="2018-10-01 13:59:32" data-original-title="01/10/2018 10:59:32" null="cerca de um mês atrás">cerca de um mês atrás</div>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">8AFPZZFHA8J114476</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">HCQ3986</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">2996/18</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">02/10/2018 11:00:26</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">MG</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Baixa Realizada</td>
        <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__NjAxNGM1Y2JkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NzY=-Y2ZjM2M5Y2JkYmI4YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NjQ=" class="list_row list_even  list_row_compact" style="" sys_id="__ENC__NjAxNGM1Y2JkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NzY=-Y2ZjM2M5Y2JkYmI4YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NjQ=" record_class="u_resultadochassi_case" collapsed="true" data-type="list2_row" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case">
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-control col-small col-center " style="white-space:nowrap;" rowspan="1">
            <span class="input-group-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista" id="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__NjAxNGM1Y2JkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NzY=-Y2ZjM2M5Y2JkYmI4YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NjQ=" name="check_u_resultadochassi_case" class="checkbox " data-type="list2_checkbox" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" data-original-title="Marcar registro para Ação de lista">
                <label for="check_u_resultadochassi_case___ENC__NjAxNGM1Y2JkYjdjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5NzY=-Y2ZjM2M5Y2JkYmI4YWZjMGNkM2QzMmZmYWE5NjE5NjQ=" style="" class="checkbox-label">
                    <span class="sr-only">Selecione o registro para ação: __ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM=</span>
                </label>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td class="list_decoration_cell col-small col-center " rowspan="1">
            <a href="u_resultadochassi_case.do?sys_id=__ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM=&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=20&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379" class="btn btn-icon table-btn-lg icon-info list_popup" data-type="list2_popup" data-list_id="u_resultadochassi_case" style="margin-left:0px" title="Visualização __ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM=" aria-label="Visualizar Registro: __ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM=" data-use-href="true" data-popover-title="__ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM=" data-popover-title-is-html="false" aria-haspop="true" role="button" aria-expanded="false" data-original-title="Visualização __ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM="></a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM=" href="task.do?sys_id=2df9c507dbfce30472b47a30ba961986&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=20&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">CS0391003</a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">
            <a class="linked formlink" aria-label="Abrir Registro: __ENC__MmRmOWM1MDdkYmZjZTMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5ODY=-ZGUzYmI2MDJkYmIwMjMwNDcyYjQ3YTMwYmE5NjE5MTM=" href="sn_customerservice_resultado_chassis.do?sys_id=de3bb602dbb0230472b47a30ba961913&amp;sysparm_view=Ralatório&amp;sysparm_record_target=u_resultadochassi_case&amp;sysparm_record_row=20&amp;sysparm_record_rows=2379&amp;sysparm_record_list=resultado_u_processoISNOTEMPTY%5Eresultado_u_situacao%3D7%5Eresultado_u_uf_gravameCONTAINSMG%5Eresultado_u_data_notificacaoBETWEENjavascript%3Ags.beginningOfLastMonth%28%29%40javascript%3Ags.endOfToday%28%29%5EORDERBYcaso_number">
                <div class="datex date-calendar" title="6 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 14:32:46" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10/2018 11:32:46</div>
                <div class="datex date-calendar-short" title="6 semanas atrás" timeago="2018-10-01 14:32:46" timeago-attrs="title" data-original-title="cerca de um mês atrás">01/10 11:32</div>
                <div class="datex date-timeago" title="01/10/2018 11:32:46" timeago="2018-10-01 14:32:46" data-original-title="01/10/2018 11:32:46" null="cerca de um mês atrás">cerca de um mês atrás</div>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">147A0373219</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">GUQ2930</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">2722/18</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">02/10/2018 11:34:12</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">MG</td>
        <td class="vt" ng-non-bindable="">Baixa Realizada</td>
        <td class="vt vt-spacer" style="padding: 0"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Desired Exit**:

*CS0390986 01/10/2018 11:25:23 95VGF5L2DEM000886 OWM7329 2411/2018 02/10/2018 11:26:35 MG Baixa Realizada*

Can you help me?

Comment: Your desired doesn't match with the labels in your picture so it's unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to print only `CS0390986` or the entire table row of data? How do you plan to determine which rows you want to print? Is it based on the data in another column or ???

Comment: Sorry, A Grid displays 20 lines per page, I want to print all the lines, I just used the CS label as an example, I updated the post with the grid HTML

Comment: Please post a minimal working HTML snippet (without the noise of other labels, etc.) and the text you want to get. From what I understand so far, you want driver.findElements(By.xpath()).stream().map(e -> e.getText()).collect(List());

Answer (score 1):

You are identifying the element to get your text from by

```
By.className("list2_body")
```

But I don't see any elements with that class name in the DOM. Is it hidden higher up?

You're basically getting the whole body, and it looks like the current output is the first element.

it looks like each row is identified by

```
data-type=list2_row
```

Then either grab the text for the whole row, or narrow it down further to each td element

Comment: Yes, let's get a way to get the text useful (Update the post with the Grid HTML)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should spend some time reviewing the HTML TABLE tags and what they do/represent.

Your locator, `By.className("list2_body")`, is getting the TBODY tag

```
<tbody class="list2_body">
```

which holds the entirety of the HTML table (excluding the column headings). That's why you're printing so much text.

It sounds like what you want is to print each table row, which would be housed in each TR tag. If you change your locator to a CSS selector, `.list2_body > tr`, and then print that, that will print a row of data at a time.